# How to calculate the percentage of a single element in the sum of all elements in a vector<float>

Tags: c++, vector, percentage

I have got a
 `vector<float>a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`
and for each element I want to get the percentage of each value within the total sum.
Which means the final result should be like 
`vector<float>b = {2.2%,4.4%,6.6%,8.8,11.1%,13.3%,15.6%,17.8%,20%}`

The size of the array is not certain. The above is just an example.

Comment: Sum the values, then divide each value by the sum, and then multiply the result by 100, and push_back that result into `b`.

Comment: Do you know how to add the elements of the vector to get a total? Do you know how to divide each element by the total to get a percentage? Do you know how to add those results to an output? Where are you running into a problem?

Comment: Quite often the way you would do something in a computer is the same as you would do it with a pen, and when it isn't starting with the pen approach at least gives you something you can experiment with to find a better path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to calculate the *total* or sum:

```
float total = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0.0f);
```

Next, you need to calculate the percentage of each item:

```
const unsigned int quantity = a.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  float percentage = (a[i] * 100.0f) / total;
  cout << percentage << ", ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: An answer that uses the STL. I like it. However, I feel like there is an STL algorithm that does a `foreach` as well that could simplify the loop.

Comment: @Chipster:  The loop is simple, so I think any use of looping STL algorithms would produce a negligible effect or make the code more readable. :-(

Comment: Do note that your call to `std::accumulate` won't compile.  You need to supply an initial value as the third parameter. `float total = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0.0f);` is what you need in this case.

Comment: Added initial value per recommendation from Nathan Oliver.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you so much. I have another question that the output of your code "percentage" is in type float, is it possible to output a float type array?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to output a float array.  Use a loop to print out each element and `cout`.  See also `std::set_precision`.    If you want something challenging use an *output iterator* for the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first sum the whole array first like this:

```
float sum = 0;
for(size_t i =0; i<a.size(); i++) {
    // add to sum. I'll let you figure this part out
}
```

Then, once you know the `sum`, you simple need to loop again and divide each variable in the vector/array by `sum`. I'll let you figure that part out too.

---

Edit: Actually, I was wrong. This will give you a probability, not a true percentage. It you want the percentage, then you will need to multiply by 100. This converts things like 0.05 into 5 (% is implied). You can do this in the same loop as the original division by doing something like this:

```
percentage = (item / sum) * 100; // () not necessary here, I think, but just for clarity...
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask if it is possible to output put a float-type array?

Comment: You're saying create a new array instead of in place? Yeah, should be fine. If it is a `std::vector` you should be able to use `percentages.push_back(...)` instead of `percentage = ...`